# Wordpress - Hook and prevent certain posts from being imported

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP ALL Import to import thousands of posts from a custom XML file. I filter it the best I can with XPath, but some conditions have to be done in PHP.

How can I hook into the process of saving the post and check certain conditions using PHP, and in case the conditions fail, prevent that single post from being saved into the DB?

I don't want to stop the whole import process though.

I found some filters (content_save_pre, pre_post_update, wp_insert_post, etc) but not sure how to implement them and more importantly how to avoid the post from being saved.

I know I can easily execute my code and delete the posts I don't need once the import process is finished, or after each post is created, but I would like to avoid inserting a post into DB just to possibly have to delete it seconds later.

Comment: you might get help quicker if you post what code you have already tried.

Comment: Might also be worth trying [Wordpress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For now, I'm using the Function Editor of WP All Import to run some checks with PHP and delete the post if I need to. I would prefer to not insert the post into the DB at all, but the upside is that I delete it to Trash and can check how did the code go. I hook to `add_action( 'pmxi_saved_post', 'my_custom_function', 10, 1 );`